# Jquery plugin for table sort is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have add some code here I am using webnots plugin to sort a particular tablE but the thing is css is loading fine but I cannot see the filters in the tables, tell me what's wrong.

source:- https://www.webnots.com/advanced-data-table-widget-for-weebly/

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.webnots.com/resources/bootstrap.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.webnots.com/resources/dataTables.bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.webnots.com/resources/bootstrap.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.webnots.com/resources/dataTables.bootstrap.css"/>
<style>
.table-responsive {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.table-responsive {
overflow-x: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<!-- This is the header section of the table -->
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Rendering engine</th>
<th>Browser</th>
<th>Platform(s)</th>
<th>Engine version</th>
<th>CSS grade</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!-- End of table header -->
<tbody>
<!-- This is the start of first row of the table -->
<tr>
<td>Trident</td>
<td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
<td>Win 95+</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>X</td>
</tr>
<!-- End of first row (copy and paste this block to append additional rows -->
<!-- Paste additional rows here -->
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://www.webnots.com/resources/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.webnots.com/resources/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.webnots.com/resources/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the browser's JS console (F12). Plugins are complaining about missing jQuery. You need to load it *before* any plugins that are using it. Eg. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Your example works when i add it: http://codepen.io/helb/pen/LWMmmW

Comment: your trick did it now its working in my browser.

Comment: hey now I am having some different issue when I upload the webpage on my website which is hosted by godady i cannot see the filter and search bars, however the tablE is showing fine.

Comment: Maybe some files are missing? Can't tell without seeing your website… Does it complain about anything in the console?

Comment: I maked that right basically there are some css and js files which are in my site that were causing the plugin to load when I resolved it , it turn out fine.. now its up and running.